# How to run the bubble(on slider top) with the slidervalue and the position same as thumb of slider?

Tags: iphone, uislider

I have a slider with the minValue = 0 and maximumValue = 1000. I have a bubble on slider which runs with the thumb of the slider and displays the value of the slider.
But i am unable to run the bubble with the slider thumb.
Here's the code snippet:

```
CGFloat sliderMax = localSlider.maximumValue;
CGFloat sliderMin = localSlider.minimumValue;
CGFloat sliderMaxMinDiff = sliderMax - sliderMin;
CGFloat sliderValue = _dsp;
CGFloat halfMax = (sliderMax+sliderMin)/2.0;
//int hMax = [halfMax intValue];
CGFloat xCoord = halfMax- 55.0;
CGFloat yCoord = (CGFloat)_positionX;
if (sliderValue > halfMax) 
    {
        xCoord = xCoord-(sliderValue-halfMax);
    }
else 
    {
        xCoord = xCoord + (halfMax-sliderValue);
    }
xCoord= xCoord + (642/sliderMaxMinDiff)*(sliderValue-sliderMin);
newB.frame = CGRectMake(xCoord,yCoord,84,47);
```

Answer (score 0):

@Ashutosh It might be of some use

```
-(void)sliderValueChanged:(id)sender{

    UISlider *slider = (UISlider*)sender;
    CGFloat sliderMin =  slider.minimumValue;
    CGFloat sliderMax = slider.maximumValue;
    CGFloat sliderMaxMinDiff = sliderMax - sliderMin;
    CGFloat sliderValue = slider.value;

    if(sliderMin < 0.0) {

        sliderValue = slider.value-sliderMin;
        sliderMax = sliderMax - sliderMin;
        sliderMin = 0.0;
        sliderMaxMinDiff = sliderMax - sliderMin;
    }

    CGFloat xCoord = ((sliderValue-sliderMin)/sliderMaxMinDiff)*[slider frame].size.width-SLIDER_CALLOUT_WIDTH/2.0;

    CGFloat halfMax = (sliderMax+sliderMin)/2.0;

    if(sliderValue > halfMax) {

        sliderValue = (sliderValue - halfMax)+(sliderMin*1.0);
        sliderValue = sliderValue/halfMax;
        sliderValue = sliderValue*11.0;

        xCoord = xCoord - sliderValue;
    }

    else if(sliderValue <  halfMax) {

        sliderValue = (halfMax - sliderValue)+(sliderMin*1.0);
        sliderValue = sliderValue/halfMax;
        sliderValue = sliderValue*11.0;

        xCoord = xCoord + sliderValue;
    }
    int index = ceil(slider.value) ;


    if (MIN_INDEX<= index <=MAX_INDEX) {
        CGPoint callOutPoint = CGPointMake(xCoord, slider.frame.origin.y);
        //[self drawCallOutAtRect:callOutPoint andDate:[self.dataSourceArray objectAtIndex:(8-index)]];     
        //Call A Function To draw Bubble on Slider Top
    }   
    previousIndex = index;
}
```

You can also take some hint from https://github.com/elc/ELCSlider

Here is a screen shot of what i made [image]

I added the slider using these values-

```
UISlider *timeSliderObj = [[UISlider alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 280, 44)];
timeSliderObj.maximumValue = 8;
timeSliderObj.minimumValue = 1;
timeSliderObj.value = 8;
```

Comment: could you please explain what are different the variables. I've got some errors and do not understand what are all those variables for.

Comment: I needed to show eight previous dates with a slider to make final seletion. so MIN_INDEX = 0 & MAX_INDEX=7, previousIndex is of type int to keep track of previous slider index(0,1,2,3etc) , No other variable is declared outside the scope of this function. What are the variables for which you get the errors ?

Comment: My calculation is working fine with the values 17(min) and 67(max) but its just not working for values ranging 0-1000 or more. It starts running backwards or do some random things. I tried to debug also and saw that after a time it goes negative.